# need to limit checkboxes to one per row using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am using the following code to create checkboxes next to each row i have.  There can be anywhere from 500-2500 rows, so the number of rows need to be dynamic.

I am trying to:

1. Copy a sheet from one workbook to another
2. After sheet is copied,add checkboxes next to each row
3. I am using conditional formatting to strike through all text in a
   row if K is TRUE, checkboxes are in J.
4. The problem I am having is, if a row is formatted not identical in
   height, two checkboxes appear in that row and it affects the
   subsequent rows.

This is what the code i am using looks like. 
Please help.

```
Sub create_new_wb_CHECKLIST()
    Sheets("Jobs by Day").Copy
    Dim ToRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyLeft As Double
    Dim MyTop As Double
    Dim MyHeight As Double
    Dim MyWidth As Double
    LastRow = Range("I20000").End(xlUp).Row
    For ToRow = 2 To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(ToRow, "I")) Then            
        MyLeft = Cells(ToRow, "J").Left
        MyTop = Cells(ToRow, "J").Top
        MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "J").Height
        MyWidth = MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "J").Width        
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
         With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "K" & ToRow
            .Display3DShading = False
         End With
      End If
  Next

List item

End Sub
```

Comment: You can set the height of each row's cell by using 'Rows(ToRow).RowHeight = X' where X your desired value to make every row's height consistent. Otherwise I'd suggest an accumulating your variable. EG: MyTop = MyTop + Rows(ToRow).RowHeight. You may have to play around with a 'magic number' offset to this accumulator value to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Kris / Scott, thank you for your prompt reply!!!  I will try right now and update.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that spacing is an issue in your current code is because you never set the `Height` of the checkbox, so it's sets to default height. The argument in the `Add` method simply tell VBA where on the sheet to *place* the checkbox, it does not seem to actually set the `Height` of the checkboxm, and thus the boxes overlap based on the row height.

I found placing a `.Height = MyHeight` inside the `With Selection` block solved it:

```
    With Selection
        .Caption = ""
        .Value = xlOff
        .LinkedCell = "K" & ToRow
        .Display3DShading = False
        .Height = myHeight
     End With
```

Comment: Scott, the .Height works good, but still having an issue with some cells getting multiple boxes.  I think it may be a formatting issue with my data and some cells maybe containing line breaks / carriage returns

Comment: Hey, I think i got it, to rid of the carriage return, i added this loop

    
    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
           If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next

Answer (score 0):

Added the following and i think i am sorted.  Apologies for the mis-formatted questions, this is my first time posting to stack.  Thanks for all of your help!!!

to rid of the carriage return, i added this loop

```
For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
       If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
        MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
    End If
Next
```